# How to validate a credit card using PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

I need to validate if a credit card provided is a valid number using PayPal API.
Is there a simple API operation/method do this? Or if not I am guessing we need to do the
direct payment to charge say $1 to client's credit card or something. What are the best way to implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do DoDirect payment with action "Authorization".

Comment: That's not the way to do it, since you'll temporarily hold the funds on the buyer's card. Unless you immediately follow your DoDirectPayment call with a DoVoid call to void the authorization. If you merely want to check the validity of the card number, Chris Kooken's answer is better. This can be done client-side as well.

Comment: We want to do the ReferenceTransaction using the ID returned from DoDirect. So it makes sense for us to utilize the validation of DoDirect while getting the reference id at the same time. Note: I do have mod-10 validation on the client side.

Comment: Ah okay, then it makes sense, yeah.

Comment: This doesn't go all the way to verify the credit card data : meaning expiration date, and ccv => is there a way to test that ?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the Paypal API do do this, I would do it before you send it to Paypal.

Google the LUHN algorithm for your respected language. You will find tons of links.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm